# Proving that $\text{Curry}F$ is a functor

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading a paper and the author makes the following assertions:

Let $F: \mathcal C \times \mathcal D \to \mathcal E$, and define $F_A: \mathcal D \to \mathcal E$ for $A$ an object of $\mathcal C$. The functor $F_A$ is defined as $F_A B = F(A,B)$ and $F_A g = F(id_A, g)$. The author then asserts that $F_A$ is a functor.

Indeed we can show that this is the case by the fact that

$$
F_A(f\circ g)=F(id_A,f\circ g) = F((id_A, f) \circ (id_A,g))
$$
Since $F$ is a functor, this means that:
$$
F((id_A, f) \circ (id_A,g)) = F(id_A, f) \circ F(id_A,g) = F_A f \circ F_A g.
$$

Similarly, we can show that
$$
F_A(id_X)=F(id_A, id_X) = id_{F(A,X)} = id_{F_A X}.
$$

Here is where things get complicated. The author defines that for $f:\mathcal C(A,B)$, we can define a natural transformation $F_f: F_A \to F_B$ where $F_f X = F(f, id_X)$. Then, he defines a functor $\text{Curry}F: \mathcal C \to \mathcal E^{\mathcal D}$ such that:
$$
\text{Curry} F A := F_A \\
\text{Curry} F f := F_f.
$$

The claim is then that $\text{Curry} F$ is a functor. I've been having a hard time proving this.

Comment: Is there a particular step causing you trouble?

Comment: I'm stuck in proving the identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to prove that $\text{Curry}F$ preserves identity morphisms and composition of morphisms. Given an object $A \in \mathcal{C}$, the natural transformation $F_{\text{id}_A}:F_A \Rightarrow F_A$ associates to an object $X \in \mathcal{D}$ the morphism $F(\text{id}_A,\text{id}_X):F_A(X) \to F_A(X)$. Since $F$ is a functor, this morphism is just the identity $\text{id}_{F_A(X)}$. Therefore, we conclude that $F_{\text{id}_A}$ is the identity natural transformation $\text{id}_{F_A}$.

Now, given two morphisms $f:A \to B$ and $g:B \to C$ in $\mathcal{C}$, the natural transformation $F_{g \circ f}:F_A \Rightarrow F_C$ associates to an object $X \in \mathcal{D}$ the morphism $F(g \circ f,\text{id}_X):F_A(X) \to F_C(X)$ while the natural transformation $F_g \circ F_f:F_A \Rightarrow F_B \Rightarrow F_C$ associates to $X$ the morphism $F(g,\text{id}_X) \circ F(f,\text{id}_X):F_A(X) \to F_B(X) \to F_C(X)$. Since $F$ is a functor, these two morphisms agree. The equality $F_{g \circ f} = F_g \circ F_f$ follows.